# Magento 2 admin panel throw error

Tags: magento2, module, sales-order

Order saving error: **Public hash should be defined**

I am go to magento 2 admin panel and sales and go throw places order this error is coming how to slove it?[image]

Comment: can you attached screen shot of error in question please ?

Comment: most probably you have a faulty implemented payment method. Are you using the standard ones from the core or something else?

Comment: ple tell me I am also share screen shot

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I'm using the default payment getway on mag 2.2.5